# Why does a simple Swift arithmetic operation compile so slow?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-compiler

In an attempt to optimize the build time of my app I've added the following to my `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS`:

```
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = 
-Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking=75
-Xfrontend -warn-long-function-bodies=75
```

I got a warnings for this specific type checking being slow, and I cannot figure out if I can help the compiler in some way here.

`var delay: TimeInterval = TimeInterval(index) * 0.05`

Any suggestions what can be done to speed up the compile time for such basic arithmetic operations up?

I'm running Xcode 11.5 with Swift 5

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Also tried explicitly casting the number to `TimeInterval`, which shouldn't be needed as all numbers are Doubles by default.
[image]

Comment: Just a word of caution: unless compile times are a huge concern for you, don't chase this dragon too far. You'll end up using less and less type inference, adding tons of type information to your code that only clutters it, only for some ms of compilation gain. Considering almost all builds are incremental and only involve a few files, it's usually not too big of a deal

Comment: Great word of caution - I won't. This is more out of curiosity. 

Answer (score 2):

The compiler performs type checks. If you have a long expression, it takes time. Sometimes when the expression is too long, you even get an error as:

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable
> time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

try something like

```
var delay: TimeInterval = TimeInterval(index) * TimeInterval(0.05)
```

Comment: `TimeInterval` is a typealias for `Double`, so you can just do `TimeInterval(index) * TimeInterval(0.05)`

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica You are right, I updated the answer

Comment: This did not help at all. In fact it made it actually worse (difficult to say that after just compiling once - but it ended up as 138 ms)

Comment: @Groot What about `var delay: TimeInterval = TimeInterval(index) * 0.05 as TimeInterval`?

Comment: No luck. 122ms @Alexander-ReinstateMonica

Comment: Just for curiosity try this: 
let timesValue: Double = 0.05 
let indexValue: Double = Double(index as Int)
var delay: TimeInterval = timesValue * indexValue

Comment: That didn't do it either. Still 120ms

Answer (score 0):

In your build settings, under 'Swift Compiler - General' check the 'Reflection Metadata Level' and try setting it to 'None'.

Since upgrading to Xcode 11.4, I had a project jump from compiling in around 20 seconds to compiling in around 6 - 7 minutes.

I noticed that it only happened in Debug builds, which is strange because Release builds perform more optimizations and should really take longer to compile. I eventually traced the slow builds back to the 'Reflection Metadata Level' setting. It is set to 'All' for 'Debug' builds by default.

This might be a bug in the Swift compiler that's included in Xcode 11.4 and later, because this setting never caused a problem for me in earlier releases. (It started happening with Swift compiler version 5.2.)